# Invalid column index undefined. Should be an integer in the range [0-8]

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
//        google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['controls'] });
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
    </script>



   <script type="text/javascript">

            function drawVisualization(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
                if (dataValues.length < 1)
                    return;

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2]);
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[3]);
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[4]);
                data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[5]);
                data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[6]);
                data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[7]);
                data.addColumn('string', 'Email');
                for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                    data.addRow([dataValues[i].Value1, dataValues[i].Value2, dataValues[i].Value3, dataValues[i].Value4, dataValues[i].Value5, dataValues[i].Value6, dataValues[i].Value7, dataValues[i].Value8, 'contactus.aspx']);
                }


                var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('TableContainer'));

                var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="{8}">{7}</a>');
                formatter.format(data, [7, 8]); // Apply formatter and set the formatted value of the first column.

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]); // Create a view with the first column only.

                table.draw(view, { allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true });

            }

        </script>
```

Breif google table chart code;refered https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=de-DE#patternformatter
i tried to add link button;i cant can anyone tell me where i am going wrong;please refer some link to me...Thank you.

Comment: i dont no why its voted down i referred https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/vyvbICBzW-A;even though i cant use a last column as integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on these lines:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="{8}">{7}</a>');
formatter.format(data, [7, 8]);
```

The numbers in the pattern refer to the indicies of the array you pass to the formatter, not to column indices.  The pattern in your case should be like this:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="{1}">{0}</a>');
```

because you want to use the first column in the formatter as the text of the link and the second column in the formatter as the href attribute.